# como manejar devolucion de arraylist en funciones?

Tags: java, arraylist, login

soy estudiante y  estoy realizando un login.
estoy desarrollando el siguiente codigo y solo obtengo como devolucion un error al momento de su ejecucion.

Binevenido a su home Banking

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        The constructor ArrayList<String>(String, String) is undefined      

        at funcionesBankApp.validacionUsuarios(funcionesBankApp.java:55)
        at bankApp.main(bankApp.java:19)
```

El codigo de el archivo de funciones es el siguiente.
funciona almacenando los usuarios en el array usuarios y los passwords en otro array llamado password.
no logro darme cuenta que estoy haciendo mal o donde esta mi error.

desde ya muchas gracias..

```
public class funcionesBankApp {


  public static ArrayList <String> validacionUsuarios(String  nombreUsuario, String passwordUsuario) {

    
    Boolean loginOK = false;
    String miUsuario = "";
    String miPassword = "";

    Scanner miTeclado = new Scanner(System.in);


     //Arraylist declaracion USUARIOS
     ArrayList<String> usuarios;

     //instancia del AL USUARIOS
     usuarios = new ArrayList<String>();
     
     //inicializacion del AL USUARIOS
     usuarios.add("nacho");
     usuarios.add("david");
     usuarios.add("natalia");

     //Arraylist declaracion PASSWORD
     ArrayList<String> passwords;

     //instancia del AL PASSWORD
     passwords = new ArrayList<String>();
     
     //inicializacion del AL PASSWORD
     passwords.add("1234");
     passwords.add("abc");
     passwords.add("rosa"); 

    while (!loginOK) { 
        System.out.println("Ingrese su Usuario:");
        miUsuario = miTeclado.nextLine();
        for (String usuario : usuarios ) {
            if (miUsuario.equals(usuario)) {
                if (usuario.equals("nacho") || usuario.equals("david") || usuario.equals("natalia")) {
                    System.out.println("Ingrese su contraseña:");
                    miPassword = miTeclado.nextLine();
                    for (String password : passwords){
                        if (miPassword.equals(password)) {
                          System.out.println("Bienvenido");
                        }
                      }
                  } 
                }
              
              return new ArrayList <String> (miUsuario, miPassword );
            }
          }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes es al llamar al constructor de ArrayList, debes pasarle el listado en lugar de 2 strings. Esta seria la forma correcta de hacerlo.

```
return new ArrayList <String> (List.of(miUsuario, miPassword)))
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta!!! no sabia que pasaba el listado y para ello se usaba List.of.